# Google script to export csv to google file stream G: location

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet that needs to be on the local computer as a CSV file. Is there a way to export it to a folder on my computer that overwrites the same file name when I press or trigger the script?

Edit: by local I mean the Google File stream G:, just needs to be in the same folder every time overwriting the file. I found the code below but each time I run the code it makes a new folder. I need it to replace the files in the same folder. Can that be done?

https://www.drzon.net/posts/export-all-google-sheets-to-csv/

Ok below is what I did and it works. It deletes the existing files first then creates new ones.

```
function saveAsCSV() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
    // folder location
  var myFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("winspc").next();
    //delete exisiting files in folder
  var files = myFolder.getFiles();
  while(files.hasNext()){
    files.next().setTrashed(true)
  }

  for (var i = 0 ; i < sheets.length ; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    // append ".csv" extension to the sheet name
    fileName = sheet.getName() + ".csv";
    // convert all available sheet data to csv format
    var csvFile = convertRangeToCsvFile_(fileName, sheet);
    // create a file in the Docs List with the given name and the csv data
    myFolder.createFile(fileName, csvFile);
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: When you say local, are you talking about your local computer, or do you mean on your Google Drive?

Comment: I was talking about getting it on the google file stream G: drive. I needed a local address, not a URL.